# Kendo UI Angular 2 Grid support for column widths gone since latest update

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After updating to the latest version (0.13.2), the Kendo Angular 2 grid has lost support for specifying column widths using the `width` attribute. When trying to bind to this attribute, the following error is thrown:

`Can't bind to 'width' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid-column'.`

Has this setting been replaced with another one that I am not aware of? The Kendo UI for Angular 2 documentation still uses the `width` attribute in the demos.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? Having same problem right now.